# How and why would the sea-scorpion wound those who hold it?

Tags: creature-design, sea-creatures, natural-defenses

The sea-scorpion is an average-sized sea creature resembling a terrestrial scorpion, and which has a rather unique feature: Despite an apparent lack of spines, claws, or other obvious methods of cutting, anyone who attempts to pick up the sea-scorpion will end up with a painful cut on their hand. This cut will manifest no matter where the sea-scorpion is grabbed. What features might the sea-scorpion have that would allow for this bizarre wounding?

Comment: eurypterids has either biting fangs or pincers depending on the species.

Comment: Why? Because [it's the scorpion's nature](https://thescorpionandthefrog.com/about/) of course!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A caraspace that contains a coarse, sharp, abrasive (similar to that of a coarse sharpening stone, but I have recently discovered that the coarseness of a dressing stick for a grinding stone is much much worse). Combined with the instinct to twitch or make sudden jerky movements When picked up. In particular, having angled edges or ridges or tiny raised conical or triangular dimples will greatly help with this by concentrating pressure.

I did this to my fingers last week when washing a dressing stick. I was aware the edges of the stick were sharp but failed to pay sufficient notice to the fact one of the end faces had a small imperfection. Just a couple of dimples sticking out smaller than your typical grain of sand. But unlike a grain of sand, it was pointy, very sharp, and wouldn't move with your finger if your finger grazed it

Answer (score 0):

The sea scorpion actually *is* covered in thin, flexible, razor sharp spines all over its body -- they are just made of a transparent hard substance with the same refractive index as the surrounding seawater, making them appear totally invisible while submerged.

Comment: This isn't very practical because then everyone would know how the scorpions wounds people as soon as picking it up.

Answer (score 0):

The sea scorpion secretes venomous solvent through its carapace that dissolves the membrane of skin cells, resulting in a nasty rash.